# search view with back icon in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

In my project I am using search view of android.
It is working properly.

But I am having one problem i.e related to back image while searchview expands.

[image]

This is my action bar with icon and other search and drawable icon.

Now when I click on search Icon

[image]

Here Icon is changes. It's by default taking launcher image. but I want it to be same as its showing in image 1.

So can any one help me with this issue.

## edit1

here is my action bar style xml.

```
 <style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabText.Example</item>
    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#99c0c0c0</item>
</style>
```

## edit2

substyle for actionbar

```
 <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example"   parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
</style>
```

## edit 3

This is my onCreateOptionsMenu method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    try {
        search = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(search,
                new OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when collapsed

                        layoutList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when expanded

                        layoutList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                });

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionView(search);

        setSearchTextColour(searchView);

        searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Debugger.debugE("on close");

                layoutList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and to show actionbar

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.app_name));
    s.setSpan(new TypeFaceSpan(getContext(),
            getString(R.string.font_gothum)), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#bb0404")));
```

There is nothing else that I had used.

note: In all other navigation from the main screen icon which is showing in first image is coming.
Issue is only with searchview.

Thanks in advance.

Bskania

Comment: Show us your actionbar style xml please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your app theme on your styles.xml

You can do something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/myicon</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I had already set icon in the manifest file. Still I need to change this?

Comment: Why don't you try it ;) Change your `<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>` to create your custom style where you define your icon.

Comment: I tried this code and it's working. Setting an actionbar icon different from the launcher will work when you click on the search view. You must be using some other code that is messing with the icon

Comment: Pedro Oliveria I had updated my code. Please check this. If any mistake is there?

Comment: It is working above version 4.0. Is there any other solution to support above 2.3.3 version?

Comment: As far as I know you will have to use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` for that

Answer (score 0):

create a custom action bar :

```
 LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_actionbar, null);
 actionBar.setCustomView(v);            
 _searchView = (SearchView)v.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
 ....
 ....
 ....
```

and define ids of views and use .